# Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

Tags: java, javac

I have created a HelloWorld.java file in Git Bash by

```
 $vi HelloWorld.java
```

Then inserted the following:

```
   class Hello { 
        public static void main (String[] arguments) {              
            System.out.println ("Hello, world!");
       }
    }
```

push esc and write :wq!

Then I tried to call the program.

```
  $ls
  HelloWorld.java
  $javac HelloWorld.java
  $ls
  Hello.class HelloWorld.Java
  $ java HelloWorld
  Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Your class is called `Hello`, not `HelloWorld`. It's also a good idea to name the file `Hello.java` and make the class public.

Comment: @ernest_k What can I do to prevent it from changing the class name from HelloWorld to Hello? I tried to change the name manually but it keeps throwing an error: Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: HelloWorld)

Comment: It's simple: you manually type `public class HelloWorld{...}` and save the file as `HelloWorld.java`. The rest of steps are the same. Java doesn't change file or class names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix few things:

1. Your main class should have public access modifier

   ```
   public class Hello {}
   ```
2. Also file name and class name should match. So if your class name is **Hello**, your file should be named **Hello.java**

Comment: I tried to do with public but it throws an error, while calling javac HelloWolrd.java:                                      HelloWorld.java:1: error: class Hello is public, should be declared in a file named Hello.java
public class Hello {

Comment: Also what can I do to prevent it from changing the class name from HelloWorld to Hello?

Comment: Like bhusak said, your filename and class name need to match. If your class is public class Hello {} then your file needs to be Hello.java - recompile when you have changed this.

Comment: You can only change your filename to match name of your class. For example, class has name HelloWorld, filename is HelloWorld.java, etc.

Comment: @MAD-HAX That worked thanks, but I still don't understand why the name have been changed? I get it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ls
Hello.java

$java Hello.java
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Please explain your code in 1 line to make it user interactive